# Extract a file path or file name from a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

Take following string as an input:

```
var input = @"The file is: ""c:\sampleDirectory\sample subdirectory\sampleFileName.txt\"" which is a text file";
```

How can I extract only the file path from the above string.
Using Regex or a similar approach is preferred.

Comment: Just get the index of the final backslash and split on it..

Comment: .Substring to read between "" the positions of which you have determined with .IndexOf

Comment: Do you really need to make it complicated with a regex? Why not use Path.GetFileName, Path.GetDirectoryName etc from System.IO (it's OS friendly too, I believe)

Comment: Or just look how MS does it on the [GitHub source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/path.cs)

Comment: @shunty those methods do work on a pure path. But in my given string, the path is mixed within a long string.

Comment: I made an edit in code sample to clarify the situation

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: @MostafaArmandi Right, now we can see that. So maybe this helps as a learning lesson to make the question a bit clearer. Now, how about `input.Split('"')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited:**

It can be done with `LastIndexOf` as answered by eocron.

But here is a regex solution :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"""(.*)\\(.*\..*)[\\]?""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{   
    string path = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string filename = match.Groups[2].value;
}
```

Comment: I realise that the question clearly has a Windows path but you should probably be using Path.DirectorySeparatorChar if you really must use regex or LastIndexOf instead of the built in operations in System.IO.Path

Comment: your solution for the given sample give me the completely wrong result: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/eYzJsT](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eYzJsT)

Comment: @MostafaArmandi I thought the string inside quotes was only given. Anyways I have done it like you wanted, edited the answer too. Here is what you want https://dotnetfiddle.net/iz9Lmv

Answer (score -3):

If your input patterns looks exactly like this, you could easily do this without Regex:

```
var magic1 = 14;//index of first quotation mark
var magic2 = 22;//suffix index of last quotation mark
var result = str.Substring(magic, str.Lenght-magic2-magic1);
```

Comment: magic answers are not appropriate on SO :[ and of course the actual file is not "sampleFileName.txt"

Comment: You can improve this by adding code to generate the result of 14/22 in that case. (So it's more generic)