# Extract full path from text string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string, where I would like all paths using regex

```
<plugin_output>
  Path              : C:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\
</plugin_output>
<plugin_output>

  KB : 4346087
  - C:\Windows\system32\mcupdate_genuineintel.dll text here to be ignored

</plugin_output>
<plugin_output>
The following instances of Java are installed on the
remote host :

  Path              : D:\apps\webtek\oracle\redhat_jdk8u242\\jre\
  Path              : D:\apps\webtek\oracle\redhat_jdk8u242\jre\
  Path              : D:\apps\webtek\oracle\redhat_jdk8u242\jre
</plugin_output>
```

I'm able to extract most of the path using this:

```
([A-Z]:)?\\.*\.*
```

but I would extract all of the paths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract a file path or file name from a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611105/extract-a-file-path-or-file-name-from-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: No, didn't answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Is regex mandatory? If not then this should be efficient for this specific type of input:

```
    public static string[] GetPaths(string text)
    {
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (line.TrimStart().StartsWith("Path") && line.Contains(":"))
                {
                    paths.Add(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim());
                }
            }
        }

        return paths.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: The code only works if the word path is included, which is not always the case. For instance this: <plugin_output>

  KB : 4346087
  - C:\Windows\system32\mcupdate_genuineintel.dll Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,

</plugin_output>